# Have anyone installed Ubuntu on a VeryPC Thinbook ("ethical" laptop)

Tags: drivers, laptop, hardware

after some research looking for a laptop with higher environmental and social standards. I found from different sources that the best option seem to be the [VeryPC Thinbook](https://very-pc.co.uk/products/laptop/thinbook#quickcontact), the most comprehensive review is [here](http://www.ethicalconsumer.org/buyersguides/computing/laptopsandnetbooks.aspx). However, they only offer it with Windows or no OS at all. I plan to install Ubuntu 18.04, and I'm worried about hardware drivers compatibility.

Have anyone tried to install any Ubuntu version on a VeryPC Thinbook?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about hardware recommendation.

Comment: @user68186 I'm not asking for hardware recommendations. I'm just asking if anyone has experience installing Ubuntu in this very specific laptop model. Which correspond to the thinbook of the brand VeryPC

Comment: Another way to reduce the environmental footprint is recycling rather than buying brand new things. There are companies in several countries, that refurbish used computers from companies and other [big] organisations and sell them with several months guarantee, which should be enough to detect if there are problems. An enterprise class computer, that is 2-4 years old will usually work very well with Ubuntu. (Examples: Dell Latitude, Dell Precision, HP Elitebook.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)